# How does one access "agreements, tax and banking" in AppStore Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I signed up for a developer account that's now become active. I'm trying to follow the in-app purchase tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5456-in-app-purchase-tutorial-getting-started).

The tutorial asks me to ensure I've accepted certain criteria in [Agreements, Tax and Banking](http://appstoreconnect.apple.com), but when I click on that, I see the header of the page loading briefly and then get redirected back to the iTunes Connect home page (see images).

[image: App Store Connect Home Screen 1]
[image: App Store Connect Screen that redirects]

Is this a known issue, and how should I proceed?

I've tried Chrome (70.0.3538.110) and Safari (12.0.1 (14606.2.104.1.1)), but the same thing happens in both. I've also downloaded the AppStoreConnect app for iOS but that doesn't seem to include administrative sections.

Comment: Have you paid the fee or are you using a free membership?

Comment: @Paulw11 I've paid the fee. $159 in Australia =(

Comment: How long ago did you sign up?  Have Apple processed all of your paper work yet?  You probably need to contact Apple support, as that section is working for me, so I don't think there is a general issue

Comment: I signed up on Sunday. On Monday they asked for my ID and a few hours later sent me the 'Welcome to App Store Connect' email. It's Thursday today in Australia. I've contacted Apple Support... I guess I'll just have to wait and see what happens.